# Selenium:Unable to get dynamic text in second loop

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get dynamic text and display it, which gets executed in a while loop. It displays the text successfully, but does not display consistently from the next iteration.

Have given implicit wait right after the click of the drop down element, so that the data gets updated on the UI. But still I do not get the desired output. Is there anything else I am missing, please let me know. 
Also, when I print the indexes of the arraylist res_arr, it outputs [].
My Code:

```
 while (i<list_size)
         {
            sl.getOptions().get(i).click();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            WebElement hcdata = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/p"));
            System.out.println("HCdata: "+hcdata.getText());
            ar.add(hcdata.getText());

            WebElement freq = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/p"));
            String freq_no = hcdata.getText().toString();
            System.out.println("Frequency: "+freq_no);
            ar.add(freq_no);


            WebElement DT = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form/div/div[3]/div[4]/div[1]/p"));
            String DT_no = hcdata.getText();
            System.out.println("DT no: "+DT_no);
            ar.add(DT_no);

             i++;

            res_arr = indexOfAll(0,ar);
            System.out.println("Inside arraylist result");

                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res_arr.toArray()));

         }

        }//end of try
        catch(Throwable e){
            System.out.println("Error found: "+e.getMessage());
        }
```

Output:

```
Size is 6 

HCdata: 12,865 

Frequency: 12,865

DT no: 12,865

Inside arraylist result

[]
HCdata:

Frequency: 

DT no: 0

Inside arraylist result

[]

HCdata: 

Frequency: 

DT no: 0

Inside arraylist result

[]

HCdata: 

Frequency: 

DT no: 16,479

Inside arraylist result

[]

HCdata: 
Frequency: 
DT no: 275
Inside IndexofAll method
Inside arraylist result
[]
HCdata: 
Frequency: 
DT no: 
Inside IndexofAll method
Inside arraylist result
[]
```

Comment: instead of using implicitwait, I suggest you use fluent wait to wait until the text not empty, and give timeout . Or you could create helper method to retry when the result still empty

something like

`while(!HCdata || timeout not reached) {
   put your code of finding element here
}`

change implicit wait and findElement combination, and use WebdriverWait

`WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(yourxpath)));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue is you're using `hcdata` for all three of your `getText()` operations.

Try the following changes:

```
String freq_no = hcdata.getText().toString();
```

to:

```
String freq_no = freq.getText().toString();
```

and

```
String DT_no = hcdata.getText();
```

to:

```
String DT_no = DT.getText();
```

Second issue is **implicit waits** only wait for an element to appear, if they are already on the page but don't have a value, it will return immediately.

What you want is an **explicit wait**. Something like:

```
sl.getOptions().get(i).click();

By hcdataBy = By.xpath("//form/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/p");
//this would wait up to 10 seconds for the wait condition. Change the 2nd parameter if longer or shorter would be better.
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>(){
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
        return d.findElement(hcdataBy).getText().length() > 0;
    }
});
```

This is a custom **ExpectedCondition**, when you can it would be best to use existing [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html)

One possible way to change this to using existing `ExpectedConditions` would be like this:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(hcdata, "")));
```

Depending on what the actual value of `getText()` is while the data is loading.

Another thing to consider for **implicit waits** is that once you set it, your tests will use that until you change it. So if you set it at the beginning of your loop, it will use that implicit wait every time your test finds an element from then on. This can lead to some confusing behavior, since it can be difficult to track when an **implicit wait** was set in the code. For this reason, and for some other timing issues and bugs, I'd suggest only using **explicit waits**.

Comment: Hi.It works. adding explicit wait, with apply method worked for me, Thank you :)